# cross tab/pivot the table and missing should be null

Tags: mysql

```
datetime               tran_value        name
2016-01-01 10:00:00      2000               x
2016-01-01 10:00:00      3000               y
2016-01-01 11:00:00      4000               z
2016-01-02 13:00:00      5000               x
2016-01-02 13:00:00      6000               z
2016-01-03 14:00:00      7000               y
```

is it possible to get output like below

```
datetime                    x          y           z
2016-01-01 10:00:00       2000        3000        null
2016-01-01 11:00:00       null        null        4000
2016-01-02 13:00:00       5000        null        6000
2016-01-03 14:00:00       null        7000        null
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made any attempts of your own to solve the problem?

Comment: @Giorgos i am beginner in queries

Comment: @user5860640 Thats doesn't give u an excuse to not try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of names in the table, then

**Query**

```
select `datetime`, 
max(case when name = 'x' then tran_value else null end) as x,
max(case when name = 'y' then tran_value else null end) as y,
max(case when name = 'z' then tran_value else null end) as z 
from tblTransactions 
group by `datetime`;
```

If not, then you have to use a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;

select
group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when name = ''',
      name, ''' then tran_value else null end) as ',name
    )
  ) into @query
from tblTransactions ;

set @query = concat('select `datetime`, ', @query, ' from tblTransactions 
              group by `datetime`
');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**Result**

```
+---------------------+------+------+------+
| datetime            | x    | y    | z    |
+---------------------+------+------+------+
| 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | 2000 | 3000 | NULL |
| 2016-01-01 11:00:00 | NULL | NULL | 4000 |
| 2016-01-02 13:00:00 | 5000 | NULL | 6000 |
| 2016-01-03 14:00:00 | NULL | 7000 | NULL |
+---------------------+------+------+------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/682e66/2)

Comment: @user5860640 : Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table name is `table1`

```
select `datetime`, 
        max(if(name='x',tran_value,null)) as x,
        max(if(name='y',tran_value,null)) as y,
        max(if(name='z',tran_value,null)) as z
 from table1 group by `datetime`
```

SQL fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54577/1

Comment: That would work only incase those are all the options

Comment: Yeah..but can add more if required otherwise it requires creation of dynamic option which to be added to query then.

Comment: Yes but if its the case, and lets say there is columns A-Z, then you should use pivot and not this

Comment: for above table we have 3 columns

Comment: how to take avg for all the above columns excluding NULL value , I have tried select avg(x) as avg_x from tblTransactions where x is not null group by datetime, now how to calculate avg's for all 3 columns once at a time excluding NULL values (in my scenario ) i have 72 columns.